# Importing large datasets via HTTP

Tags: feeds

I'm having trouble importing a very large dataset with feeds. It's about 8mb of text in XML format. It imports impossibly slow (I started it about a month ago and it's still not finished).

However, if I run the exact same importer with the same file I upload from my computer, it runs in about two minutes.

The thing is, I need to check the stock of my products from my supplier through this file every hour. Most of the data is irrelevant other than stock info.

Are there any good alternatives to do what I'm trying to do? (Drupal Commerce)
I've been thinking that if I have another module retrieve the file from my supplier every hour, then I could just point feeds to the file on my own server. However, I'm having trouble finding a module that does that file retrieve.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A month-long operation is a good sign that something went wrong? How did you launch the import? If you used a Web GUI, the operation probably timed-out without updating the UI. I doubt your webserver is configured to allow a month-long HTTP request processing. Are you able to connect to the server to check if a PHP process is indeed still running?

Instead of looking for a module to download the imported file every hour, you could rely on a simple [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget) to download the file:

```
0 * * * * wget http://my.supplier.com/products.xml -a /var/log/supplier-products-download.log --no-verbose -O /some/path/products.xml
```

If I remember correctly, the default XML parser for Feeds uses [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). It will load the complete XML tree in memory beofore processing it. For a 8Mb file this could start to be an issue (depending on your PHP memory configuration). A beast approach would be to write your own Feed parser ([as a Feeds plugin](https://drupal.org/node/622700)) using the [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) API which support a streaming mode (ie. data are processed when reading the file).

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's still running, it's been increasing consistently when I check it (currently at 49%).

I'll give the cron job with curl/wget a try, then point my feeds to that downloaded file. I probably won't get to it for a few weeks though, then I'll try and remember to update this post with my results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple drupal module that downloads one file using php. I call it feeds_downloader and this is the **feeds_downloader.module**.

I usually run the downloader using [elysia_cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) or [ultimate_cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron).

In my case I download an array of files and this module is a bit different (contains a loop). And they are of 1GB size or more.

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_cron()
 * Create a cron job
 */
function feeds_downloader_cron() {
  // Get last cron run
  $last_run = variable_get('feeds_downloader_last_cron', 0);

  // Default interval every 20 hrs.
  $interval = variable_get('feeds_downloader_interval', 60 * 60 * 20);

  // Run cron if it is time to run
  if(time() - $last_run > $interval){
    variable_set('feeds_downloader_last_cron', time());

    // Run the download function

    // Where to save the file
    $path = "public://feeds";
    // Where to download the file from
    $url = "http://example.com/my_file.xml";
    // The local filename that will be saved
    $name = "my_file.xml";
    feeds_downloader_curl_list($path, $url, $name);
  }
}

/**
 * A function to download files using curl.
 * @param string $path
 * @param string $url
 * @param string $name
 */
function feeds_downloader_curl_list($path = "public://", $url, $name){
  if ($url == "" || $name == ""){
    return;
  }
  // Get real path of $path
  $path = drupal_realpath($path);

  // Local file of the file to be saved
  $filename = $path . "/" . $name;

  // Optional, for large files. Disable time limit
  set_time_limit(0);

  // Create file
  $fp = fopen($filename, "w+");

  // Initialize curl
  $ch = curl_init();
  // Add url
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
  // Allow redirects
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTREDIR, 3);
  // Set timeout
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
  // Write curl response to file
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

  // Run curl - download
  $results = curl_exec($ch);

  // Get info about download
  $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  $message = t("File %file with size: %size_download MB downloaded on
    %date from %url");
  $message_variables = array(
    '%url' => $info['url'],
    '%size_download' => $info['size_download']/1000000,
    '%date' => format_date($info['filetime'], $type = 'medium'),
    '%file' => $name,
  );

  // Debug download if there is no error
  if(!curl_errno($ch)) {
    // Create a watchdog message
    watchdog("feeds_downloader", $message, $message_variables, WATCHDOG_INFO);
  } else {
    watchdog("feeds_downloader", $message, $message_variables, WATCHDOG_ERROR);
  }

  // Close curl function
  curl_close($ch);

  // Close file
  fclose($fp);
}
```